# Multi-Org clarification

Tags: marketing-cloud, architecture, multi-org

I am a little confused about the multi-org architecture. Two quick questions that I would like to be clarified:

- Is the All Contact list shared with all of the Business Units or are separated (even if they point to the same environment)?
- Is the All Subscribers list shared with all of the Business Units or are separated (even if they point to the same environment)?
- How this architecture impact in the preference center?

Apart from that, from your experience, is there anything I should have into account apart of the stuff mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Contacts and All Subscribers are shared across the enterprise.

In your preference center make sure that you know how opting out of All Subscribers will affect your business units. Any master unsubscribe from the parent business unit will affect all child business units. You have the choice of whether or not master unsubscribes at a child business unit get recorded at the enterprise level or business unit level.

Make sure your roles restrict access to All Subscribers for anyone that's authorized to work in a single Business Unit only.

All Contacts are visible in every Business Unit in Contact Builder so make sure to restrict Contact Builder for anyone that cannot view All Contacts within your Account.

Comment: While true, I believe he's asking about the multi-org SF connector configuration.  In the case of multi-org, it's in-essence putting a E2.0 configuration back to the E1.0 configuration, where all subscribers are siloed by BU.

Comment: So you're saying you can't configure the child business units to master unsubscribe at the parent level when using the multi org connector?

Comment: Yes, subscribers are siloed by BU because each one could be connected to a different SF Org.

Comment: That's strange because in the Account I'm working in which is an Enterprise 2.0 account, using the multi-org connector, it has at least 3 business units connected to 3 different SF Orgs. I'm able to view a subscriber from one business unit in the other, and vice versa. I'm also able to apply master unsubscribes from the Child BU to the Parent BU. In All Subscribers the subscriber count matches across all BUs. Why would that be?

Comment: Perhaps someone who knows why the multi-org config is irreversible can weigh in a shed some light on why the counts are the same.  There'd need to be some view for all contacts for billing purposes, so in that regard, it seems reasonable.  Applying unsubscribes between BUs... how so?

Comment: It seems that even SFMC documentation is somewhat contradictory inside of what is possible with Multi-Org. for instance the FAQ(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5) mentions a Custom Profile Center is not needed, but the Multi-Org config documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&type=5) states that a CPC IS required. Most of the time I have heard descriptions saying Multi-Org is more similar to the capabilities in an E1.0 account. Which means reduced capabilities in each BU.

Comment: I also wanted to mention that according to the docs now, that SFDEs cannot be shared but MC DEs and All Subs can be shared (with permissions controlling who views what). As I mentioned previously though, the docs seem to be inaccurate, or at least inaccurate enough to cast doubt on the validity of the info.