# Which feature will not work after enabling multi org in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, multi-org

We want to enable multi org in marketing cloud as we are connecting one org to multiple salesforce instances so after enabling which functionality will no longer available?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial quote from Salesforce:

> **Is Sharing Salesforce Data Extensions (SFDEs) Across Business Units
>   (BUs) Allowed?** No. Sharing SFDEs in a Multi-Org account isn’t
>   supported, even between BUs connected to the same org. Sharing
>   standard Data Extensions and content is supported.
>
> **Is Personalization Supported in Multi-Org?** Yes, for standard fields
>   only. Using custom fields from the Sales Cloud requires AMPScript.
>
> **Is the Standard Profile Center Supported in Multi-Org?** No. Custom
>   Profile Centers are required for Multi-Org.
>
> **Is Web Collect Supported?** No.
>
> **Is One Custom Profile Center (CPC) Per Business Unit Required?** No. One
>   CPC per Business Unit is an option, but is not required. Other options
>   include one CPC that manages business unit unsubscribes, or multiple
>   CPCs that align with key departments, publications, or verticals in
>   your business. It is important that you manage unsubscribes to remain
>   CAN-SPAM compliant.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5

Please be advised that the change to Multi-Org Setup cant be undone and check if your use case really needs this kind of setup.

Comment: Although the documentation says otherwise, I’ve seen Standard Profile Centers work perfectly fine with Multi-org. Take a look at this thread for more info: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239074/multi-org-clarification

Comment: I back-up what @zuzannamj said. You need custom PC to support different "preferences" for different BU's but from tech perspective it will still work ok